# ASPNET Core - Json response stops at the related model

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, relation

I have two classes that have relations between them. They are Market and Promotion classes. I'm facing a problem when I make a request. The json result stops when it comes to the relation.

The Market class:

```
    public class Market : BaseModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        // GPS informations.
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid PictureId { get; set; }
        public Picture Picture { get; set; }

        public List<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
    }
```

The Promotion class:

```
        public class Promotion : BaseModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid PictureId { get; set; }
        public Picture Picture { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid MarketId { get; set; }
        public Market Market { get; set; }
    }
```

When I make the next request, I got an incomplete answer.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Market>>> Get()
        {
            var markets = await _context.Markets
                .Include(m => m.Owner)
                .Include(m => m.Picture)
                .Include(m => m.Promotions)
                .ToListAsync();

            return markets;
        }
```

The response json stops when get at MarketId of the first promotion.

```
    ...
        "pictureType": 0,
        "pictureUrl": "https://superbarato.azurewebsites.net/api/Pictures/url/d6bc07a8-db55-4ee5-7342-08d73f6147e9",
        "id": "d6bc07a8-db55-4ee5-7342-08d73f6147e9",
        "createdAt": "2019-09-22T13:34:26.9367403",
        "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "deletedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ownerId": "75c1f286-c07f-4e50-dda0-08d73f61058f",
        "owner": null
    },
    "promotions": [
        {
            "description": "Açúcar Camil 1Kg",
            "price": 5.0,
            "pictureId": "e7af68b9-c053-4f4b-7344-08d73f6147e9",
            "picture": null,
            "marketId": "e2962be8-1a19-418a-6ce7-08d73f62308d"
```

How to get all the promotions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Core  , you could configure Json.NET to ignore cycles that it finds in the object graph. This is done in the `ConfigureServices(...)` method in `Startup.cs`.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );
```

Another alternative is to decorate one of the navigation properties with the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, which instructs Json.NET to not traverse that navigation property while serializing.

Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization

Answer (score 0):

The problem of yours is that `Market` and `Promotion` types/instances are referencing each other and you got into a cycle serializing those two indefinitely. You may solve it by projecting database model without relationship to response model/structure to avoid that.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MarketModel>>> Get()
{
    var markets = await _context.Markets
        .Select(m => new MarketModel {
            Name = m.Name,
            // Other properties needed to be serialized to response body
            Promotions = m.Promotions.Select(p => new PromotionModel {
                Description = p.Description,
                // Other properties needed to be serialized to response body
                MarketId = p.Market.Id
            }
        }
        .ToListAsync();

    return markets;
}

public class MarketModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Other properties needed to be serialized to response body

    public List<PromotionModel> Promotions { get; set; }
}

public class PromotionModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Other properties needed to be serialized to response body

    public Guid MarketId { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps.